# Printing text in html in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a next question-tried to find it with google, but didn't find what could help me. I have a big HTML file that I need to print, to separate pages I use CSS `break-after`.
The quesion is: **how can I print an element in the center of the page, not only horizontal center but vertical too**. The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media all {
                body
                {
                    text-align:left;
                }
                p.paragrpahs
                {
                    text-align:center;
                    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                    font-size:32px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    vertical-align: center;
                }
                .break_here
                {
                    page-break-before:always;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        *Tons of text*
        <p class="break_here"><p class="paragrpahs">Some text</p><p class="break_here">
        *Tons of text*
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this would be the best option in the world but this is how I did it. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/kCB7J/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is `vertical-align: middle`, not `vertical-align: center`, see [MDN - vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

There's a nice article about centering at [CSS Tricks - Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). Transfering this to your example, you must first set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
p.paragrpahs {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then add the mentioned "ghost" element

```
p.paragrpahs:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p.paragrpahs {
  height: 100%;
}

p.paragrpahs:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
*Tons of text*
<p class="break_here">
  <p class="paragrpahs">Some text</p>
  <p class="break_here">
    *Tons of text*
```

This will give you a vertically centered text on a whole page, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghUuk/). When you use `p.paragrpahs` (sic?) for other things as well, you should add a separate `vcenter` class or similar, of course.

*Update:*

With longer text (more than one line), this doesn't work, unfortunately. If you have longer text, you can wrap the text into a `span` element

```
<p class="paragrpahs"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</span></p>
```

and give this a

```
p.paragrpahs span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p.paragrpahs {
  height: 100%;
}

p.paragrpahs:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p.paragrpahs span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
*Tons of text*
<p class="break_here">
  <p class="paragrpahs"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</span></p>
  <p class="break_here">
    *Tons of text*
```

Then this `inline-block` `span` will again vertically align with the ghost (`:before`) element.

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghUuk/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I used the folowing css:
.center
{
height: 100%;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:32px;
font-weight:bold;
vertical-align: middle;
}
But when I have big text, that is splits in 2 lines the 2nd line goes to the next page or goes to the bottom of the page- I've tried that in mozila.

Comment: I think it's because of display property in css, but how can I fix it?
`p.center:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

Comment: You're right, this doesn't work with two or more lines. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This `flex` approach worked for me.

In the CSS:

```
@media print {
    div.centerOnPrintedPage {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<div class="centerOnPrintedPage">
    <h3>This page intentionally left blank.</h3>
</div>
```

Tested in Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming .paper_card is your outermost styled div during printing, the following CSS will force each one to one page, stretch it to fit the print page ( and adjust for paper size ).

```
  div.paper_card {
    position: relative;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 90vh;
    border: 1vh solid #ee6e73;
    border-radius: 5vh;
    margin: 20px auto;
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  @media print {
    div.paper_card {  
      margin: 0px auto; 
      top: 0px; 
      bottom: 0px; 
      width: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  }
```

Note that you should use vh sizing for all internal elements to get it to scale to various paper sizes.